# Honda A12 Maintenance Service (14 Civic EX 38K miles)

Tags: honda, scheduled-maintenance

I want to know if this A12 service (oil change, tire rotation, air filter) is covered under warranty or if this maintenance service is supposed to be paid out-of-pocket if serviced at the dealership. I ask this because I am the 2nd owner and not the original owner. Also, the vehicle sold (to me) privately and not via any dealership. I have no ties to the original dealership that sold the vehicle.

Comment: In most cases maintenance is NOT covered whether a new vehicle or not. There are only a few makes which have it covered (BMW would be one). Unless the dealership has some deal, Honda as a manufacturer doesn't. What would lead you to believe it would have some type of maintenance warranty?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Absolutely no reason. My first car in a new country, so I don't know how the original warranty would work. Thanks for the insight and I appreciate it. If you can put that as an answer, I'll close the question.

Comment: I'm on my phone so cannot tell where you reside. May help with an actual answer which is valid. I was speaking for the States. May not be the same in South Africa or Timbuctu :o)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the question pertains to USA. I am from a different country. Thanks.